# Make Google search box appear smoother when rendering page

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-search, search-box

The following code is used for a site's search function.  The Javascript is provided by Google.

```
<div id="search" class="cf">
  <script>
    (function () {
      var cx = '00000000000';
      var gcse = document.createElement('script');
      gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
      gcse.async = true;
      gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })();
  </script>
  <gcse:search></gcse:search>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#search {
  width:60%;
  margin-left:40px;
}
```

The following is rendered when the page is loaded.

[image: Description]

Everything is great, except that when the search box is first rendered, it appears squeezed horizontally for a fraction of a second while the javascript is being loaded, until it finally acquires its final width.  It appears jerky and unpleasant visually.  As you can see, the width for the div is defined.

How can this search box be rendered more smoothly?

```js
(function() {
  var cx = '005029469966757601490:wu1xlk8ufeu';
  var gcse = document.createElement('script');
  gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
  gcse.async = true;
  gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 4.3em;
}

#menu {
  margin: 0 0 5px 15px;
  width: 10%;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  background: #F1C232;
  line-height: 40px;
}

#menu a {
  color: white;
}

#search {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="container">
  <div id="menu">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div id="search">
    <gcse:search></gcse:search>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**  Here's a more accurate description of the problem: While the search widget is still loading, the magnifying glass icon at first appears closer towards the middle of the widget's display area instead of at the end where it belongs. When the widget is fully loaded, the magnifying glass icon moves to the right.

Comment: It's hard to visualize what you mean, and the code you've shared doesn't do that, so a working example for us to look at would go a long way here.

Comment: Yeah it loads fine for me

Comment: I have added a full code snippet.  The jerky effect is not very pronounced on desktop, so I'm not sure if you'll be able to see it by running the code snippet, but it's very noticeable on mobile.  You can still see the delayed loading of the search bar even on desktop.

Comment: I think I can describe the effect with more precision now.  While the search widget is still loading, the magnifying glass icon at first appears closer towards the middle of the widget's display area instead of at the end where it belongs.  When the widget is fully loaded, the magnifying glass icon moves to the right.

Comment: It looks just fine on iOS (iPad)